# How do I load a 3rd party JS library into my Angular6 project?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

There is an awesome JS library called 't.js'. It's used to make a cool looking typewriter effect. This library cannot be downloaded via `npm`, you have to download its t.min.js file.

Usually when adding libraries to an Angular6 project, you have to install it via `npm`, but as I said, you can't. So I tried pasting a `script` tag in my html file to reference it. But, now it keeps giving me an error:

```
$(...).t is not a function
```

You can check out t.js' website [here](https://mntn-dev.github.io/t.js/).
You will then see their documentation and understand the use of the `.t` I used.

So does anyone maybe know how I can add a 3rd party JS library to my Angular6 project when it can't be installed via `npm`?

After some Google-ing some people said the error is that the library is `.js` and not `.ts`, if this helps.

Here is also some of the code I used:

```
<script src="assets/t.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(() => {
    $('#main').t({
      beep: true,
      caret: '<span style="color: hotpink;">·</span>',
      typing: (elm, chr) => {
        if (chr.match(/\-trigger/)) {
          $('#pow-txt').show().delay(500).fadeOut(0);
        }
      }
    });
  }, 4200);
});
```

I would also recommend this [video](https://youtu.be/39NZDe95_g0).

Comment: 1) That can be accomplish with pure CSS 2) don't use jquery code in Angular applications. it's bad practice. I have been programming on angular since it came out and I never had the need to use jQuery.

Comment: There's at least 3 other vanilla js solutions that aren't jquery plugins, you'd be better served using [https://www.google.com/search?q=vanilla+js+typewriter+effect&oq=vanilla+js+typewriter+effect&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i64.6843j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8](one of those.)

Comment: Thanks, @Adam, but I have searched for some vanilla js typewriter plugins, but none seem to meet the style of the one I'm trying to use.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use jquery in angular it will cause so many problems later. But if you want to do this cool stuff in angular then you can easily do that by adding a script tag in `index.html` file.

Following are some steps that you can follow to achieve what you need:-

1. Add assets folder and put your jquery.js and t.js file.
2. Link these script in `index.html`. ex

   ```html
       <script src="./assets/js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="./assets/js/t.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   ```
3. In your component ts file you have to declare `jQuery` variable to link it with global `jQuery` variable. Use this variable to do all jquery operation.

In component ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
declare var jQuery;
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Angular';

  runDemo1() {
    jQuery('#demo_1').t({
      beep: true,
      caret: '<span style="color:hotpink;">•</span>',
      typing: function (elm, chr) {
        if (chr.match(/\-trigger/))
          jQuery('#pow-txt').show().delay(500).fadeOut(0);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

In component html file

```
<button (click)="runDemo1()">Run demo</button>

<pre id="demo_1">
######<ins><span id="pow-txt" style="display:none;color:tomato;">---[POW!]</span></ins>
##<del>\<ins>1.5</ins></del><del id="pow-trigger">|</del>\
</pre>
```

you can follow this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ndymhh)

Comment: Thanks @Vikash Dahiya, but it still gives me the error:

jQuery(...).t is not a function

Answer (score -1):

That looks like an error that'd be thrown if jQuery isn't installed & loaded. As an alternative, you could try TypeIt, an animated typing utility I wrote. It has no jQuery dependency, and can be easily installed with `npm`: `npm install typeit`.

Site/Docs:
https://typeitjs.com/

Github:
https://github.com/alexmacarthur/typeit